# Characterization of convergence with liminf and limsup

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I am reading a text which claims the following:

Assume that
\begin{align} \tag{1}
\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \leq a < b \leq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n.
\end{align}
Then for any $\varepsilon > (b-a)/2$ we have
\begin{align} \tag{2}
\sup_{m \leq k < \infty} |x_k - x_m| \geq \varepsilon
\end{align}
for all $m \geq 0$.

Now I wonder about the choice of $\varepsilon$. Why should (2) hold for large $\varepsilon$? It seems to me that (2) holds precisely for all $\varepsilon \in [0,b-a]$. Is this correct?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: I would guess they meant $\epsilon <\dots.$ You are correct that it holds for $\epsilon=b-a.$ But it could hold for larger $\epsilon,$ say where $\liminf x_n < a < b < \limsup x_n.$

Comment: But why do they use $(b-a)/2$ and not $b-a$ as the critical value.

Comment: The critical value is $\limsup-\liminf.$ I don't know why they chose $(b-a)/2.$

Answer (score -2):

Agree with the response given.  The problem is probably with the hypothesis of the question because given its current state if we claim that

> Suppose that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sup x_n= b > a= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} inf x_n$. 
> Then $\sup_{0\leq m<k\leq \infty}|x_k-x_m|=b-a$.

Thus if we pick $\epsilon=b>b-a$, then the claim will not work anymore.
I am not too sure why they made such a choice for the $\epsilon$ given that $\epsilon $ can take any value.